# PowerShell CSV file conversion errors due PC with different DateTime format that the input file

Tags: powershell, datetime

I’m using PowerShell with a script to convert a .CSV raw data file into more manageable data format with separate columns, a cleaner view etc. And because the source file with the raw data is in US date and time format (e.g. 11/23/21, 1:00 PM), then if the PC is in that same US format the conversion process runs perfectly as should with 0 errors. BUT, if the PC is in a different country date and time format, then PowerShell shows errors in red in the process.

When the PC is in other DateTime format I see the main error is:

"***Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.***"

And the problem is the PC where this will be used is not in US format (only changed to US format for testing), so could someone here please help me to add to the conversion process the syntax or sentence/s to simply specify directly in the code a fixed format that keeps a static output format independently about the PC clock date and time format, and if one of the inputs into the file is “11/23/21, 1:00 PM” then to specify in the code you want the output in the format “dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm” **to have a result like “23-Nov-2021 01:00 PM”**

The code section in the script used for the conversion is:

```
…
$data = $csvData | ? {$_ -match "\(DTRE"}

dtreFileData = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]

foreach ($item in $data)
{
  $null = $item.Strategy -match "\(DTRE\|(.*)\)"
  $v = $Matches[1] -split '\|'

  $resultvalue = $v[0] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal
  $expectedvalue = $v[1] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal

  $dtreData = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'DateTime' = ([datetime]::Parse($item.'Date/Time'))
    'ResultValue' = [decimal]$resultvalue
    'ExpectedValue' = [decimal]$expectedvalue
    }
  
  $null = $dtreFileData.Add($dtreData)
  $null = $dtreAllData.Add($dtreData)
}

$dtreFileData | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $f -Parent) ($outFile + '.csv')) -Force -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
…
```

**Example of raw source data (in the CVS file are dozens of lines like the next one):**

...(DTRE|49.0|48.2);...;11/23/21, 12:58 PM...;

...(DTRE|52.1|52.0);...;11/23/21, 1:00 PM...;

...

...

**And the Output looks like:**

[image]

I tried with DateTime examples in other posts from here (stackoverflow.com) to adjust the code to work in a PC without US date and time format and to get the DateTime format result described above. Examples like:

`'DateTime' = ([datetime]::Parse($item.'yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss'))`

`'DateTime' = ([datetime]::ParseExact($item.'yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss'))`

```
…
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
…
  'DateTime' = ([datetime]::ParseExact($item.'yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss', $culture))
…
```

But with these examples PowerShell shows the error “***Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null***”

Update after the answer from @Seth:

When trying next modification of the code, with the PC system date format in “24-Nov-21” and leaving the rest as above:

```
…
$resultvalue = $v[0] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal
$expectedvalue = $v[1] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal
$cultureInfo= New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")

$dtreData = [PSCustomObject]@{
  'DateTime' = ([System.DateTime]::Parse($item.'Date/Time', $cultureInfo))
  'ResultValue' = [decimal]$resultvalue
  'ExpectedValue' = [decimal]$expectedvalue
…
```

then, PowerShell shows the next errors:
[image]

Comment: The CSV file should have a specification which makes it clear the format in which dates and times will be presented. Good idea to use ISO-8601.  It is not clear what `$item` is in the question.  `([datetime]::ParseExact('2021-11-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null))` works. It would be helpful to show some example date in the question.

Comment: Thanks @lit. I updated the post showing the 3 times `$item` is into the script file. I tried with `'DateTime' = ([datetime]::Parse($item.'yyyy-MM-dd'))` but PowerShell gives errors: **"Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null."** I don't know if maybe the part where says `-Encoding ASCII` could be causing the format problem, but I tried to change it to `-Encoding BigEndianUnicode` and `-Encoding UTF32` and also the same errors. I also show how is the format in the "raw data" and how looks after the conversion, but the problem is I don't work in US format.

Comment: Please note the script runs perfectly when the PC calendar/clock is in US format, making a perfect conversion except because it shows the date in US format with the month in first place. And the conversion problem comes when the PC is another calendar/clock format that is exactly the situation where the script needs to be used. So what I need is a "generic" way where I can specify into the code that every DateTime item be converted to a specific format like `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm` (**23-Nov-2021 01:00 PM**). A generic and fixed way that works regardless of the date and time format in the PC.

Comment: The most direct solution to this situation is to control the process that creates the CSV data. It must always create it in a specific format. Use `yyyy-MM-DD` for dates. Always. If you cannot control the creation of the CSV data, then you could specify a parameter to your reading script to indicate the date format. You could also use try/catch for several formats to see if one of them works, but that would not be reliable. The solution is to correct the creation of the CSV data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @lit. The code isn't created by me and I don't know if maybe you say to modify the last line:  `$dtreFileData | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $f -Parent) ($outFile + '.csv')) -Force -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII` maybe changing `-Encoding ASCII`. I tried changing `ASCII` to others but PowerShell gives errors when I do that. Could you please show your solution as an answer showing what would be the exact modification you mean? what would need to be added and what would be to be modified. You can take the code and do what you need to show the how.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been explained it's a good idea to fix the CSV to have a better dateformat. An example would be ISO 8601 which can be used with [`Get-Date -Format "o"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier).

That said [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.2) relies on C# stuff in the background. So you can use C# code to read [that in a particular culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime). As you know the origin culture this should work. Fixing the timestamp is still a better idea.

```
$cultureInfo= New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
$dateString = "11/23/21, 12:58 PM";
$dateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse($dateString, $cultureInfo);
Get-Date -Format "o" $dateTime
```

With this example code you'd assign `$dateString` the value of `$item.' Date/Time'` and the result you likely want would be the result of `Get-Date`. So you'd assign `$dtreData.'DateTime'` the result of that `Get-Date` call. Alternatively it is possible to use the .NET DateTime Object to directly convert to a particular culture. For instance by calling `$dateTime.ToString((New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ES")))`. Though not all that useful you could also pass the format identifier to this method. This might be relevant if you want to avoid creating additional objects. A somewhat unnecessary call would be `$dateTime.ToString("o", (New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ES")))` (as format o is the same in every culture).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Seth but no solution yet. I tried modifying the code with your lines, but I’m still unable to get the date and time in a format specified directly in the code, saying “take every DateTime value in the CSV input file and convert them to the format `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm`, or for example to the culture name `es-ES`, or something similar”, i.e. being specified directly in the code as an universal/generic way where this works regardless if the PC is in English date and time format, or if the PC is in Spanish date and time format, or if the PC is in French date and time format

Comment: With your lines, I tried the next modification of the code, with the PC system date in US format: `$resultvalue = $v[0] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal`
 `$expectedvalue = $v[1] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal`
`$cultureInfo= New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")`
`$dtreData = [PSCustomObject]@{`
`'DateTime' = ([System.DateTime]::Parse($item.'Date/Time', $cultureInfo))`
`'ResultValue' = [decimal]$resultvalue`
`'ExpectedValue' = [decimal]$expectedvalue }` and the conversion works without errors, but giving the result in US format & being dependent on the OS date format.

Comment: I also tried the next modification of the code, with the PC system date format in “24-Nov-21”: `…$resultvalue = $v[0] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal` `$expectedvalue = $v[1] | Convert-CurrencyStringToDecimal` `$cultureInfo= New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")` `$dtreData = [PSCustomObject]@{` `'DateTime' = ([System.DateTime]::Parse($item.'Date/Time', $cultureInfo))` `'ResultValue' = [decimal]$resultvalue` `'ExpectedValue' = [decimal]$expectedvalue` and here PowerShell gives errors saying: “Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null”

Comment: About `Get-Date -Format "o" $dateTime` I really don’t know where would be its place in the posted code in the question. I tried to put it in multiple places like in the last line, or after  `'DateTime' = ([System.DateTime]::Parse($item.'Date/Time', $cultureInfo))`, or into it, but PowerShell gives errors. About `$dateString = "11/23/21, 12:58 PM";` I didn’t use this part because I see it would be an input example and in this case the input DateTime values are already into the CSV file that are the values that need to be worked.

Comment: In case you know how @Seth, could you please modify the code posted in the question above and add it the needed modifications to have the result I need for the date and the time. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You are creating a datetime object with a specific culture. You'd want your `$dtreData` to be `Get-Date -Format "o" $dateTime`. A `Get-Date` using `$dateTime` as input should also use your regular locale. Alternatively you could explicitly define the locale to output e.g. using `$localDT.ToString((New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ES")))`.